# Qt Creator linker error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_core249d.lib'

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, kinect

I'm building a Kinect app using Qt and C++ and I need to use the OpenCV library. I have correctly installed OpenCV and included the OpenCV header `<opencv2\opencv.hpp>` in my source file, and that's the only header I'll be using. I tried building my project in visual studio and it worked out fine, but now I'm trying to build the project in Qt Creator and it's giving me this build error:

> LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_core249d.lib'

So here is my project file:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------
# This file is generated by the Qt Visual Studio Add-in.
# ------------------------------------------------------

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = MM_demo
DESTDIR = ../Debug
QT += core opengl widgets gui
CONFIG += debug


#include directories
KINECT_INC_DIR = $$(KINECTSDK10_DIR)inc
OPENCV_INC_DIR = $$(OPENCV_DIR)\include

#library directories
OPENCV_LIB_DIR = $$(OPENCV_LIBRARY_DIR)
KINECT_LIB_DIR = $$(KINECTSDK10_DIR)lib\amd64

DEFINES += QT_OPENGL_LIB QT_WIDGETS_LIB
INCLUDEPATH += $$KINECT_INC_DIR $$OPENCV_INC_DIR
DEPENDPATH += $$OPENCV_LIB_DIR $$KINECT_LIB_DIR

message(opencv lib directory $$OPENCV_LIB_DIR)
message(kinect lib directory $$KINECT_LIB_DIR)


LIBS += -L"." \
    -lopencv_core249d \
    -lkinect10 \

MOC_DIR += ./GeneratedFiles/debug
OBJECTS_DIR += debug
UI_DIR += ./GeneratedFiles
RCC_DIR += ./GeneratedFiles
include(MM_demo.pri)
```

I'm using Qt 5.5.2 MSVC2013 64bit on Window 8.1. My OpenCV environment variables are: `OPENCV_DIR`: `C:\opencv\build` and `OPENCV_LIB_DIR`: `C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib`

My OpenCV include directory is `C:\opencv\build\include` and its library directory is `C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib`. I'm sure I have put the right include and library paths in the .pro file. I've been searching for a solution all day and saw some similar linker issues on the web but none of them solved my issue. I'll be thankful to anyone who has an idea of what's going wrong with my .pro file or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set *OPENCV_LIB_DIR*  as environment variable but it needs to be *OPENCV_LIBRARY_DIR* because the operating system has no information on the first term in the line below but it will look for the second variable:

```
OPENCV_LIB_DIR = $$(OPENCV_LIBRARY_DIR)
```